# How to convert selected image in Xamarin to byte array then to string ,while the string will be attached to an api

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

the current code is working but the converted base64string output is attached to the api , but am having 404 error because the request url is too long. so i just need modification , to shorten the converted base64string. or any different approach.

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions { PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small });

byte[] imageArray = null;

if (file != null)
{

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        imageArray = ms.ToArray();
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Comment: you can't make the encoded string shorter without corrupting it.  You can resize the image before encoding it.  But you really need to look at the API requirements - passing an Base64 encoded image via the url is unusual and really not a good design

Comment: it would also help if you posted the code for your http request

Comment: How can i resize the image

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about resizing images

Comment: please [edit] your question, do not stuff relevant code in a comment.  And I don't see anything that looks like an image in that querystring